# Bridge two ethernet interfaces in virtualbox. CentOS 7

Tags: centos, virtualbox, bridge

I created the test environment in the VirtualBox:
Three virtual machines:
1 - like end-point host (IP static 192.168.1.2) - one ethernet interface connected to virtual lan (intnet1)
2 - like bridge host (IP 192.168.1.1) - two ethernet interfaces connected to virtual lan (intnet1 intnet2 respectively)
3 - like end-point host (IP static 192.168.1.3) - one ethernet interface connected to virtual lan (intnet2)

All machines clearly installed CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

configurations of network interfaces:
*Machine-1*: (/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3)

> TYPE=Ethernet
> BOOTPROTO=static
> IPADDR=192.168.1.2
>   NETMASK=255.255.255.0
>  NM_CONTROLLED=no
>  NAME=enp0s3
>  DEVICE=enp0s3
> ONBOOT=yes

*Machine-3*: (/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3)

> TYPE=Ethernet
> BOOTPROTO=static
> IPADDR=192.168.1.3
>   NETMASK=255.255.255.0
>  NM_CONTROLLED=no
>  NAME=enp0s3
>  DEVICE=enp0s3
> ONBOOT=yes

*Machine-2*: (/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0)

> TYPE=Ethernet
> NM_CONTROLLED=no
> DEVICE=enp0s3
> ONBOOT=yes
> BRIDGE=br0

*Machine-2*: (/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1)

> TYPE=Ethernet
> NM_CONTROLLED=no
> DEVICE=enp0s8
> ONBOOT=yes
> BRIDGE=br0

*Machine-2*: (/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0)

> DEVICE=br0
> TYPE=Bridge
> STP=off
> ONBOOT=yes
> BOOTPROTO=none
> IPADDR=192.168.1.1
> NETMASK=255.255.255.0
> NM_CONTROLLED=no

When I starts all interfaces on all machines:
Machine-1 can reach with Machine-2 via enp0s3
Machine-3 can not reach any other machine and other machine can not reach the Machine-3

How using Machine[1,3] reach any of them usign bridge?

What I doing wrong? Or may be I forgott to something else...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While trying to ping any machine I see right MAC-addresses of destinations hosts. But no packages in tcpdump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to enable promiscuous mode for ethernet interfaces in settings for virtual machine-2. After that bridge works fine for me.